# Javscript upper case function not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Hi just wondering if anyone could explain this syntax error to me.
Im mapping over and object and trying to access the values through object.keys

```
 const getPokemonCard = (pokemonId) => {
    const { id, name } = pokemonData[`${pokemonId}`]
    const sprite = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonId}.png`
    return (
        <Grid item xs={4} key={pokemonId}>
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image={sprite}
                    style={{
                        width: '130px',
                        height: '130px'
                    }}
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography>
                        {`#${id}. ${firstLetterUpperCase(name)}`}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

I have figured out a solution but dont quite understand it.

```
const firstLetterUpperCase = (name) => {
name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
   }
```

gives me an error

Line 19:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

but when i remove the brackets it works

```
const firstLetterUpperCase = (name) => 
name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
```

Comment: The first example `firstLetterUpperCase` doesn't return anything. The second uses an implicit return. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: In the first example, because you've used curly brackets, you need to explicitly `return` the result from the function. In the second, because of how an implied return with an arrow function works, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, you have used curly brackets. This means (according to JavaScript [ES6](https://es6.io/) arrow function syntax) you have to provide the return keyword. Otherwise, the function won't return anything.

What happens in the second instance is you have removed the curly brackets so you no longer need to use the return keyword.

Below is a simple arrow function breakdown from a traditional function.

```
// Traditional Function
function (a){
  return a + 100;
}


// 1. Remove the word "function" and place arrow between the argument and opening body bracket
(a) => {
  return a + 100;
}

// 2. Remove the body brackets and word "return" -- the return is implied.
(a) => a + 100;

// 3. Remove the argument parentheses
a => a + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does return undefined since you didn't return it

```
const firstLetterUpperCase = (name) => {
  name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
}
```

But when you do this it returns value

```
const firstLetterUpperCase = (name) => 
name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'return' operator when you use brackets for an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

**“ arrow functions do not magically guess what or when you want to return “  MDN**

If the arrow function is one-lined, we don't need to use the return keyword; otherwise, we need to use it to tell the function which value you want to return.

We need to explicitly use return in this case :

```
 const greetingfun = (name) => {
    let greeting=`Hello ${name}`; 
     return greeting;
    }
```

We don't need to use the return keyword in this case :

```
 const function1 = name => `Hello ${name}`;
```

** As you can see here, we didn't use parentheses for the argument; since we only have one, but if you have multiple, you'll need to use parentheses around the arguments.*